# Spring MVC object passed with model attribute is empty

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute

i have problem with `@ModelAttribute`,

`CustEntity` have objects like "name" etc. also have list of `BankAccEntity` called bankAcc which has number and name.

in GET method  when i use `getBankAcc()` my cust has arraylist with bankaccounts, but when i pass object "customer" from GET to POST, he has [] in `BankAcc` list;/

my code fragment is below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/aaa.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String aaaGet(Model m, Principal principal) {

...
    CustEntity cust = custService.getCustByUserName(principal);
    cust.getBankAcc();

    m.addAttribute("customer", cust);

...
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/aaa.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String aaaPost(
        @ModelAttribute("customer") CustomerEntity cust,
        BindingResult results, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        Model m) {

    cust.getBankAcc();

    ...
}
```

regards,
swierzy

Answer (score 1):

In aaaPost, CustomerEntity cust will be binding with the data in your form.
That is, cust in aaaPost is not the one that you put in the model in aaaGet.

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck with this problem and got a solution:

Add spring form to your page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

And use form like this:

```
<form:form action="/someUrl" modelAttribute="objectName" method="post">
     <form:input path="fieldName"/>
     <button type="submit">buttonName</button>
</form:form>
```